# Android studios - How to pass image from gallery to another activity

Tags: android, android-activity, bitmap

I rarely ask on stackoverflow, but I asked a questions recently and got a great answer! so I'll try again!

I've been working on a very simple photofilter app that adds the effect through code.

What I've been struggling with is to send a picture from whenever I open up gallery to choose a picture to another activity. I mean, I would like to choose a image from gallery, then send it to a preview activity.

Whenever I take a photo from the camera, it works and I get the photo with the added filter, but my problem is that whenever I choose an image from gallery, my app crashes. I tried to use URI instead but it didn't turn out well so I rather convert the picture I take to a bitmap and thereafter send it to the activity. Could anyone help me with this please?

Thank you!

MainAcitivty

```
package com.example.alek.leszealots;

import java.io.File;

import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.content.Intent;

import android.net.Uri;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    //Deklarasjoner for fremtidlig var
    Button galleryButton;
    Button cameraButton;
    public static final int PICK_IMAGE = 1;
    private static final int CAMERA_REQUEST = 1;
    Bitmap thumbnail;
    int CAPTURE_REQUEST;
    Uri thumbFile;
    File mTempFile;
    int REQUEST_CODE_CHOOSE_PICTURE = 1;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        //Gjør klar menu knappene
        galleryButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        cameraButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);

        //Gallery knapp
        galleryButton.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                /*Intent getIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                getIntent.setType("image/*");

                Intent pickIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                pickIntent.setType("image/*");

                Intent chooserIntent = Intent.createChooser(getIntent, "Select Image");
                chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, new Intent[] {pickIntent});

                startActivityForResult(chooserIntent, PICK_IMAGE);*/
                Intent photoPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                photoPickerIntent.setType("image/*");
                photoPickerIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_LOCAL_ONLY, false);
                startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(photoPickerIntent,"Complete Action Using"), PICK_IMAGE);
            }
        });


        //Camera knapp
        cameraButton.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAPTURE_REQUEST);
            }

        });
    }
    //Sender lagret bilde i bitmap til sendImage som deretter sender videre til NextActivity i extra
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            if (requestCode == CAPTURE_REQUEST) {
                thumbnail = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
                sendImage();
            }
            else if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE) {
                thumbnail = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
                sendImage();
            }
        }
    }


    private void sendImage() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, NextActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("image", thumbnail);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

NextActivity

```
package test.test;

import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.ColorMatrix;
import android.graphics.ColorMatrixColorFilter;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class NextActivity extends AppCompatActivity {



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_next);
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        //Ser ut som denne kan ta imot fra Gallery option også.
        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        if (extras != null) {
            Bitmap image = (Bitmap) extras.get("image");
            if (image != null) {
                imageView.setImageBitmap(changeBitmapContrastBrightness(image, 20, -255));
            }
        }
    }
    public static Bitmap changeBitmapContrastBrightness(Bitmap bmp, float contrast, float brightness)
    {
        ColorMatrix cm = new ColorMatrix(new float[]
                {
                        contrast, 0, 0, 0, brightness,
                        0, contrast, 0, 0, brightness,
                        0, 0, contrast, 0, brightness,
                        0, 0, 0, 1, 0
                });

        Bitmap ret = Bitmap.createBitmap(bmp.getWidth(), bmp.getHeight(), bmp.getConfig());

        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(ret);

        Paint paint = new Paint();
        paint.setColorFilter(new ColorMatrixColorFilter(cm));
        canvas.drawBitmap(bmp, 0, 0, paint);

        return ret;
    }
}
```

activity_next

```
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="330dp"
        android:layout_height="369dp"
        app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="38dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="37dp" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

activity_main

```
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="105dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="189dp" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Edit:

https://pastebin.com/Ukc2Ui4g

Comment: In the future, please provide the Java stack trace with your question about app crashes. Usually, we cannot help you with a crash without knowing what the exception is and where it came from.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/Ukc2Ui4g

Comment: `ACTION_GET_CONTENT` does not return a `"data"` extra. It returns a `Uri`, which you get by calling `getData()` on the `Intent` passed into `onActivityResult()`.

Comment: @CommonsWare so you mean that I need to redo the onActivityResult method so that it sends the Uri data, thereafter a command picks it up, goes to the file location and puts it up as a bitmap?

Comment: I tried using your method, but I keep getting a 

`java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=1, result=-1, data=Intent { dat=content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/image:83 flg=0x1 }} to activity {com.example.alek.leszealots/com.example.alek.leszealots.MainActivity}:`

Comment: Most likely, your problem has changed. You need to look at the *full* stack trace, not just the first line, and find out where in your `onActivityResult()` you are having a problem. In your current question, your stack trace has `Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.Object android.os.Bundle.get(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference`, and shows the exact line number in your code that is causing the crash. You need to do the same thing with all future crashes.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/n9TQZQiY , Like this?

It looks like it can't do sendImage() , but I have no idea why. Is it because it's expecting a bitmap but can't get one? or is it that the path file isn't working? This is kind of why I really don't want to use URI and rather just get a bitmap as quick as possible... I'm sorry.

Comment: Sending bitmaps between components (e.g., activities) is risky, due to the error that you are getting. Perhaps these should not be two separate activities, but be one activity (e.g., with two fragments).

Comment: I can't unfortunately. I need to send it to another activity.

Comment: Then send the `Uri`, not the `Bitmap` (via `setData()` on the `Intent`, with `addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION)` as well, so `NextActivity` has the right to read the content identified by the `Uri`).

Comment: I kept trying for two hours now but I keep getting the same error.

Comment: Ah, okay thank you so much. I finally managed to do it the way you told me. Took me a few hours but I finally got my head around it and understood all the code! You're a saint.